# change aspx extension for pdf extension in Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have a code that writes a pdf file into an aspx page, but the problem is that when I want to save this file it saves with aspx extension... for example:

It saves as **myPDFfile.aspx** and I want to save it as **myPDFfile.pdf**

and I have to change the extension to .pdf to be able to open it.

How can I change the extension programatically?

My code:

```
Dim pdfPath As String = path + Session("factura").ToString.Trim + ".pdf"
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim buffer As [Byte]() = client.DownloadData(pdfPath)
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString())
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `Content-Disposition` header :

```
Dim pdfPath As String = path + Session("factura").ToString.Trim + ".pdf"
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim buffer As [Byte]() = client.DownloadData(pdfPath)
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString())

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myPDFfile.pdf")

Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
```

You should also read [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) as it will leads you to potential issue with filename characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `content-disposition` header with the file name.

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myPDFfile.pdf");
```

This is part of [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), section 19.